# How to create scatter matrix in Vega-Lite where row/columns are identified by value (not column name)

Tags: vega-lite

Can I create a scatter matrix like https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/interactive_splom but where the column/rows are created from categorical values and not column names?

The following example tries to make a scatter matrix based on 3 values from a Gaussian bivariate distribution. But it only displays one row

```
{
   "mark": "point",
   "encoding": {
      "x": {
         "field": "value"
      },
      "y": {
         "field": "value"
      },
      "row": {
         "field": "coordinate"
      },
      "column": {
         "field": "coordinate"
      }
   },
   "data": {
      "values": [
         {
            "value": -0.5600273,
            "coordinate": 1
         },
         {
            "value": -0.31220084,
            "coordinate": 2
         },
         {
            "value": -0.37932342,
            "coordinate": 1
         },
         {
            "value": -0.799277,
            "coordinate": 2
         },
         {
            "value": -1.8596855,
            "coordinate": 1
         },
         {
            "value": -3.100046,
            "coordinate": 2
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your data what you expect to appear in the other two panels. Which data rows would be associated with each other when plotting coordinate 1 vs coordinate 2?

I'm going to assume you can modify your data such that it has a third field that specifies which points go together; if that's the case, you can use a [pivot transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/pivot.html) to turn your values into columns, and then use the [repeat operator](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/repeat.html) as in the example you linked to ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtJqm8AtAAwB0ArAGymkBMA7AMwA0IAxgPZcBOYASwB20DPACM7AA5dhUCQF9WBdGLhlyzcfXp0AHABZ23PoJFQ19abKHy44pSqLqKzRgE5m9Zgauce-MKiEtZy8PSOIMiqJBQe7kyMxgFmwXB+MmHpkdHOxOLkepTu1EWUyaZBFiEgmbbwzDmEasTM5OJ0pAbUFYHmlqH1cI0AukogULwQQlgAZnwAtnigUgKIXHb+lf0g7LlqUc27IADmvFxoUgBGAJ54tTbyYyPsvBhSGNDwoOcA7vfiY70EAvfzoBZCAFAkHjLAfDjfEALCC8ADW8AeYXYGCE3DMJ0RAA9EbMBBgUGBEW8Pl84GC0BCQOMoDcPhiAI5oaZQAQwHmIMTjO4IECk8mUkXUz6bP5M9gstl0znc3nQNaChSaoA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"value": -0.5600273, "coordinate": 1, "point": 1},
      {"value": -0.31220084, "coordinate": 2, "point": 1},
      {"value": -0.37932342, "coordinate": 1, "point": 2},
      {"value": -0.799277, "coordinate": 2, "point": 2},
      {"value": -1.8596855, "coordinate": 1, "point": 3},
      {"value": -3.100046, "coordinate": 2, "point":3}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"pivot": "coordinate", "value": "value", "groupby": ["point"]}
  ],
  "repeat": {"row": ["1", "2"], "column": ["1", "2"]},
  "spec": {
    "mark": "point",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"field": {"repeat": "column"}, "type": "quantitative"},
      "y": {"field": {"repeat": "row"}, "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

If you can't add that to your dataset and you just want adjacent values to be treated as part of the same point, you can specify this using a series of transforms to construct the `"point"` field and recover the same chart ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtJqm8AtAAwB0ArAGymkBMA7AMwA0IAxgPZcBOYASwB20DPACMAX1YF0YuGXLNx9enQAcAFnbc+gkVHn1psogorNGATmb1mm+jp79hoiSZDI5JCtatNGJz1XQ3hjGU9CeWJxcnVKK2p4yiCXA3kpCK8zYmZycTpSTWpU-Tc4YwBdaRAoXgghLAAzPgBbPFAAd2EwLk6OkC4AB3gQXj6AfSE0VoAjDF4QdggcOBAhrmEoEElqiI5UDjQUcs4MARQACkgoGfINrYACAHpH+gBKJZAV0YehbY8QwEiC42zWujSbnY2XkkW87AA5uM0ENZgBPPDrTb-EDVSrsXgYIYYaDwUDjfpwXAgcRfei4pzoVpCTG09j0vYgLDEjhkkCtCC8ADWv2x23YGCE3H0CL5AA8+U0BBgUGA+YTiaTwVwmSyalA0cTRgBHNANKACGAWxBiGoYhAgJUqtUOjUksFjPo7dgGo1rU3my3QYG2yRhoA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"value": -0.5600273, "coordinate": 1},
      {"value": -0.31220084, "coordinate": 2},
      {"value": -0.37932342, "coordinate": 1},
      {"value": -0.799277, "coordinate": 2},
      {"value": -1.8596855, "coordinate": 1},
      {"value": -3.100046, "coordinate": 2}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"op": "row_number", "as": "point"}]},
    {"calculate": "ceil(datum.point / 2)", "as": "point"},
    {"pivot": "coordinate", "value": "value", "groupby": ["point"]}
  ],
  "repeat": {"row": ["1", "2"], "column": ["1", "2"]},
  "spec": {
    "mark": "point",
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"field": {"repeat": "column"}, "type": "quantitative"},
      "y": {"field": {"repeat": "row"}, "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. Is it possible to achieve the same without explicitly typing the numbers in repeat, i.e. create a vega-lite specification which works independent of coordinates?